# I'm missing something to send long audios recorded in the web browser to oracle apex?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I am trying to send recorded audio from the web browser to Oracle Apex but a problem is happening when the audio is quite long. The code works very well when the audio is less than two minutes.

What I know, the data is sent by URL, therefore it is being sent in text format. Oracle has a 32k limit for the string, so if the blob exceeds that limit, it must be sent in an array divided into parts of 30k each. So I am suspecting that the array is not being sent in the correct format, but I don't know how to confirm it.

The code I am using is as follows: (I built a plugin for Apex to send the audio)

- Fragment in Javascript that sends the audio:

```
    // builds a js array from long string
    clob2Array: function(clob, size, array) {
        loopCount = Math.floor(clob.length / size) + 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
            array.push(clob.slice(size * i, size * (i + 1)));
        }
        return array;
    },
    // converts DataURI to base64 string
    dataURI2base64: function(dataURI) { 
        var base64 = dataURI.substr(dataURI.indexOf(',') + 1); 
        return base64;
    },

    blobToDataURL: function(blob, callback) {
        var a = new FileReader();
        a.onload = function(e) {callback(e.target.result);}
        a.readAsDataURL(blob);
    },
    // save to DB function
    save2Db: function(pAjaxIdentifier, pRegionId, pAudio, callback) { 
        apexAudio.blobToDataURL(pAudio, function(data){ 
            // audio DataURI to base64
            var base64 = apexAudio.dataURI2base64(data);
            // split base64 clob string to f01 array length 30k
            var f01Array = new Array(); 
            f01Array = apexAudio.clob2Array(base64, 30000, f01Array); 

            // Apex Ajax Call        
            apex.server.plugin(pAjaxIdentifier, {
                f01: f01Array,
            }, {
                dataType: 'html',
                // SUCESS function
                success: function() {
                    // add apex event
                    $('#' + pRegionId).trigger('apexaudio-saved-db');
                    // callback
                    callback();
                },
                // ERROR function
                error: function(xhr, pMessage) {
                    // add apex event
                    $('#' + pRegionId).trigger('apexaudio-error-db');
                    console.log('save2Db: apex.server.plugin ERROR:', pMessage);
                    // callback
                    callback();
                }
            });
        });  
    }
```

- The PL/SQL Code that receives adn transforms the string array into blob

```
    DECLARE
      --
      l_collection_name VARCHAR2(100);
      l_blob            BLOB;
      l_filename        VARCHAR2(100);
      l_mime_type       VARCHAR2(100);
      l_token           VARCHAR2(32000);
      --
    BEGIN
      -- get defaults
      l_filename  := 'audio_' || to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') || '.webm';
      l_mime_type := 'audio/webm';

      -- build BLOB from f01 30k Array
      dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_blob,
                               TRUE,
                               dbms_lob.session);

      FOR i IN 1 .. apex_application.g_f01.count LOOP
        l_token := wwv_flow.g_f01(i);

        IF length(l_token) > 0 THEN
            dbms_lob.append(l_blob                                
                           ,to_blob(utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_token))));                     
        END IF;
      END LOOP;

      l_collection_name := 'APEX_AUDIO';

      APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_OR_TRUNCATE_COLLECTION(
        p_collection_name => l_collection_name);


      -- add collection member (only if BLOB not null)
      IF dbms_lob.getlength(l_blob) IS NOT NULL THEN

        apex_collection.add_member(p_collection_name => l_collection_name,
                                   p_c001            => l_filename, -- filename
                                   p_c002            => l_mime_type, -- mime_type
                                   p_d001            => SYSDATE, -- date created
                                   p_blob001         => l_blob); -- BLOB audio content
      END IF;
    END;
```

I repeat, the code works perfectly if the audio is short, but if it is long, the following error arises:

```
2020-02-20T20:09:27.169Z SEVERE <P-fvMwI2WpKybDySZRumRQ> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PLS-00306: number or wrong type arguments when calling 'AJAX'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 2:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

InternalServerException [statusCode=500, reasons=[]]
        at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApexContext.handleError(ModApexContext.java:288)
        at oracle.dbtools.apex.OWA.execute(OWA.java:206)
        at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.handleRequest(ModApex.java:310)
        at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.doPost(ModApex.java:188)
        at oracle.dbtools.apex.ModApex.service(ModApex.java:112)
        at oracle.dbtools.http.entrypoint.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:126)
        [...]
```

Tecnology:

- Oracle 12c
- Oracle Apex 19.2
- Ords 19.4
- Tomcat 8

Comment: Why not just make an ORDS Rest point and POST/PUT the blob directly ? blob in the body then the rest source just :body to insert it somewhere. much less code.

Comment: to avoid creating multiple ORDS Rest points every time I want to record audio in different web apps. Also never try to handle blob in an ORDS Rest point, but I'm going to try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thus you are sending your request using AJAX with content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" Tomcat is limiting the max allowed POST size (defaults to 2MB).
To make it work in APEX you have possibly 2 ways

1) Do some kind of double chunked upload, so first you split the file itself with e.g. file.slice() and then you build the 30k base64 array of each file chunk and upload this, chunk by chunk

2) Use a "multipart/form-data" content type with an form submit, thus here you are not running in Tomcats limitation of 2MB.

I built a file uploader plugin some time ago, just have a look at this function:

https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-dropzone/blob/90a82f4bb83fee9d78458af790560fb6c5b77978/server/js/apexdropzone.js#L378

The uploaded file will then be inserted into apex_application_files automatically, from there you can grab it:

https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-dropzone/blob/90a82f4bb83fee9d78458af790560fb6c5b77978/source/render_region.sql#L332

I would not recommend doing it with ORDS when you can do it inside of your APEX app, thus you have to deal with security, additional authentication etc...

Comment: Edit: You could also set Tomcats maxPostSize parameter, if you have access to the server settings, then you won't need any code change...But you have to do it in every environment your app runs...
https://github.com/Dani3lSun/apex-plugin-dropzone#hint-for-ords-and-tomcat-users

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I had no idea of the Tomcat limit, now I'm going to make the adjustments and let you know how it went

Comment: I opted for the first option, and it worked very well. Thank you